# Delete duplicate rows in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, delete-row

I have a dataset, there are duplicate observations, how to keep the unique observation?

```
ID   Date   Type
1   201301  A
2   201308  B
4   201303  R
1   201301  A
3   201305  C
2   201308  B
```

What I want is:

```
ID   Date   Type
1   201301  A
2   201308  B
4   201303  R
3   201305  C
```

I tried the unique & duplicated function. But it didn't work.

```
dataset[which(dataset$ID %in% unique(dataset$ID)),]  # will keep all the row

dataset[!duplicated(dataset$ID),] #will only keep the ID=3,4,as follows
ID   Date   Type
4   201303  R
3   201305  C
```

How can I get the target dataset in R?

Comment: When i try your second code (`dataset[!duplicated(dataset$ID),]`) with your dataset it does output your target dataset and not just a dataset with only ID 3 and 4...

Comment: Yes,you are right! It worked in the example data! Then why in my real dataset the function "duplicated" will delete all records that have two or more entries.Let me check again,thank you! Is there any other function that will remain one entry  while the other duplicated one is removed?

Comment: I am sooo sorry,I made a mistake.
The code(dataset[!duplicated(dataset$ID),]) can output my target dataset!

Comment: `unique(dataset)` also seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Yes,you are right.I didn't know the unique function can work for a dataset.I thought it can only input a variable in the bracket.Many thanks!

Comment: @Sunny maybe you want to close this question as it seems to have been answered?

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
unique(dataset)
```

or

```
dataset[!duplicated(dataset),]
```

will work.

(Copying the answer from the comments into a proper answer).