# what command can i use to remove duplicate values?

Tags: r

Good night, i have a file like this

```
City Lat   Long  Mals 
Bog 1m2sS 05M34W 2000 
Bog 1m2sS 05M34W 2000 
Bog 1m2sS 05M34W 3500 
Bog 6m3sS 10M34W 3400
```

I want to get a file like the following:

```
City Lat   Long  Mals
Bog 1m2sS 05M34W 2000
Bog 1m2sS 05M34W 3500
Bog 6m3sS 10M34W 3400
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: YOu can just do `unique(df1)` in `base R`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete duplicate rows in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308320/delete-duplicate-rows-in-r)

Comment: `dplyr::distinct()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967063/remove-duplicated-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unique` from `base R`

```
unique(df1)
#  City   Lat   Long Mals
#1  Bog 1m2sS 05M34W 2000
#3  Bog 1m2sS 05M34W 3500
#4  Bog 6m3sS 10M34W 3400
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(City = c("Bog", "Bog", "Bog", "Bog"), Lat = c("1m2sS", 
"1m2sS", "1m2sS", "6m3sS"), Long = c("05M34W", "05M34W", "05M34W", 
"10M34W"), Mals = c(2000L, 2000L, 3500L, 3400L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun 
i was trying this but it gave error
tablef<-unique(table, order(CITY, DEPTO_FARM, LAT, LONG))

Comment: @JohannaRamirez that won't work.  YOu may need `unique(table[with(table, order(CITY, DEPTO_FARM, LAT, LONG)),])`

Comment: I had tried too, but it didn't work, however unique (data) is working for now...thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @JohannaRamirez do you have a data.frame or tibble or data.table

Comment: I have a data.frame

Comment: @JohannaRamirez ii am not sure about the structure of your data.  THe code is working with the data in my post `unique(df1[with(df1, order(City, Lat, Long, Mals)), ])`

Comment: this is the error that appears, but previously you have read the variables, i don't understand                                                                                                               repli <- unique(table[with(table, order(CITY, DEPTO_FARM, LAT, LONG)),])
Error in order(CITY, DEPTO_FARM, LAT, LONG) : oggetto "CITY" non trovato

Comment: @JohannaRamirez can you please translate that error  in english.  Is it because you have a different column name?

Comment: sorry, "CITY" object not found.  No, the names are correct, but I can't understand what's going on...

Comment: @JohannaRamirez if you look at my data, the column name is "City". instead of "CITY' and it iis working fine.  Here, in the order, it is ordering first by 'CITY', 'DEPTO', 'FARM', LAT, LONG assuming these columns are found in the data, and it returns an index that is used as row index to order the rows

Comment: @JohannaRamirez what is the output of `with(table, CITY)`

Comment: the result are the values of City Var, i.e. "Bogota" "Cali" "Villavc"...etc

Comment: @JohannaRamirez, then it should have worked for you.  Can you update your post with the `dput` of data i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(table)))`.  It gives the structure of your data so that I can test whether there is any issue in that dataset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212438/discussion-between-johanna-ramirez-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

It would help to have more information, like an example of your data.

You can use the `janitor` package to identify duplicate responses:

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

# Get all duplicates
df %>% get_dupes()

# Get duplicates for a specified variable
df %>% get_dupes(var_name)
```